# PHP XML select node without naming it

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have a XML which is on an external server, recalling this is no problem.
Now the problem is, I want to select a path, without naming it.

So for example:

```
<data num_results="2">
   <node>
      <raw_text>
      </raw_text>
   </node>
</data>
```

And i now recall it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($link);
foreach($xml->data->node as $report) {
   process;
}
```

And i want to recall it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($link);
foreach($xml->data->[something without naming it "node"] as $report) {
   process;
}
```

How do i do this?

Cheers!

Comment: please note: the path in your foreach should be `$xml->node`, the `<data>` node is represented in `$xml`.

Answer (score 0):

use **`*`** as a placeholder in `xpath`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

foreach ($xml->xpath("/data/*") as $result) 
    echo $result->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<node>
  <raw_text></raw_text>
</node>
```

see it working: https://eval.in/508332

Note that the `xpath` method returns an array of `SimpleXml` objects.